# In what cases can this Error Log Appear

Tags: android, html, webview

```
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:114)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:33)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.DataLoader.<init>(DataLoader.java:51)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.FrameLoader.handleLocalFile(FrameLoader.java:209)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.FrameLoader.executeLoad(FrameLoader.java:129)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.startLoadingResource(BrowserFrame.java:748)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.LoadListener.nativeAddData(Native Method)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.LoadListener.commitLoad(LoadListener.java:1230)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.LoadListener.handleMessage(LoadListener.java:214)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:632)
01-13 09:36:59.934: W/System.err(1368):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

I load an HTML file to a webview using its URL by WebView.loadUrl(url), Now in some Devices it works fine, and in others (HTC Desire for instance) i get that error log on logcat. I am really confused and wasted alot of time trying to understand this so please help me out!

maybe it has something to do with the HTML fie itself? because some other HTML did get shown by  WebView.loadUrl(url) in the same device, but then, what could be the problem with the HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something weird going on with WebView.loadUrl()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404838/something-weird-going-on-with-webview-loadurl)

Comment: @Ahmad That question has been removed.

Comment: From the looks of the callstack and the code file itself (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/harmony/luni/util/Base64.java.html) it looks like it's failing to do a Base64 decode because the output buffer wasn't large enough. Best part of the file: `// approximate output length`

Answer (score 2):

Something in your code is attempting to access a non-existent member (index) of an array.  That's what the exception *means*.

Comment: its not my code, its Java and Android's WebView's Code! notice the lines of which methods this problem heppened

Comment: @OfekRon Technically, it's Apache Software Foundation's code. Though the android webkit code preceding it might be trying to decode something it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm not convinced, that's a truncated stack trace (or at least it looks like it to me).  Either way, *something* is accessing an array illegally.